# Problem when using pyqt tablewidget, float numbers are displayed with an apostrophe for all fractional parts

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

When using pyqt tablewidget, I find that when the data is a float number and there is only one integer digit, its fractional parts is incorrectly displayed as an ellipsis. This is strange, with or without the textElideMode set to ElideNone. As shown below.

first cell all fractional parts are displayed as apostrophe

[image]

textElideMode already set to ElideNone

[image]

Problems still exist when textElideMode set to ElideRight
[image]

Is this a bug? How to fix it？

Comment: Uncheck the **wordWrap** property.